# plotting with symbols on x and y axis

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, plot, matlab-figure

[image]

Hi, I would like to have the above figure, it could be coded on matlab or python (might be good to learn to do how in both languages though). Do you guys have similar experience before?

Comment: Seems easy enough as long as you have a way to reference those characters. In pyplot you would just need a list of those characters in order and it would work fine.

Comment: @Bill, do you have any example how can assign such symbolic value to axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly simple in Matlab:

```matlab
    % with tex interpreter
figure;
subplot(1,2,1)
xticks([0:.2:1])
name_of_ticks=({'\alpha','\beta','c^3','\delta^5','\delta^{\kappa}'});
xticklabels(name_of_ticks)
set(gca,'TickLabelInterpreter', 'tex');
    % with more complex latex interpreter
subplot(1,2,2)
xticks([0:.2:1])
name_of_ticks=({'$\alpha$','$\beta$','$c^3$','$\delta^5$','$\delta^{\kappa}$'});
xticklabels(name_of_ticks)
set(gca,'TickLabelInterpreter', 'latex');
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. A follow up question, if I want to fill the region with + sign, do you also know how can I do that? You can consider any simple area between lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

nums = [0,1,2,3]
chars = ["$δ^0$","$δ^1$","$δ^2$","$δ^3$"]
plt.xticks(nums,chars)
plt.show()
```

This plot will look like:
[image]

Comment: All the other features from the example could likewise be reproduced

Comment: Thanks a lot. Good to know python version as well.